# Modem apparently not broadcasting any signal

Tags: wireless-networking, modem

I just got a brand new Greenpacket DV-350, but can only use it through Ethernet. Even Wi-Fi Inspector can’t find any signal. I tested with different devices like a smartphone and even game consoles and still cannot detect a signal.

If there is a switch on the body or something, then the manufacturer is a bloody ninja, because I can’t find it.

Comment: Have you looked at the web config at all?

Comment: What have you done to make it broadcast WiFi? Was there a manual describing the required procedure?